# How to hook chmod a+r to svn-controlled files?

Tags: svn, permissions, hook

I have a webpage I'm in charge of and I've placed it inside my SVN trunk. Every time I update files I need to chmod a+r them  (I think since svn up unhooks the files first and then it recreates them with the default mask which gives no read access).

As you can infer, the webserver lives in unixland, I would like to arrange that all the svn-controlled files in some subdirectory will have a+r access mode. is this a task for a special umask? or a svn hook?

I have no idea...

Thanks!

Comment: your case? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139315/can-i-run-a-script-when-i-commit-to-subversion

Comment: I'm not sure, all these hooks seem to be running on the serverside. and in any case they do not to be a post-update hook. or am I mistaken? Also, I'm not sure that a hook is the correct thing to do, hence the question.

Answer (score 1):

What is your UMASK set to? When I do a checkout on Subversion, my permissions are `rw-r--r--` for files and `rwxr-xr-x` for directories.

There's no Subversion hook for mere updates or checkouts.