# how to write a svn hook script

Tags: svn, post, hook, commit

I'm trying to write a post commit hook script for svn to export repository to team foundation server. (So when you commit a code, that latest version of the code gets copied to team foundation repo )

Only language I use is C++ and C and I have never written a script. Can anybody give me step by step  instruction for this? which language to use, what to read etc... along with some example code possibly ??

Is it possible to write a hook script with c++? or should I learn how to use python or ruby etc..

Comment: Firstly, [answers are already available here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139315/can-i-run-a-script-when-i-commit-to-subversion). Secondly: no. It doesn't have to be a "script". Anything with an executable bit works. You could write your hooks in C or C++, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write your hook using C or C++ if you like. Most people use Perl or Python.

The main thing is that `svnlook` should be used in your hook script and not `svn`. svnlook is faster and safer than `svn`. In fact, in pre-commit scripts, you have to use `svnlook` since you don't have a repository revision.

Here are some things to keep in mind about your `post-commit` hook:

- You cannot change a revision, and don't try to commit changes. Your post-commit hook will end up calling itself. If you want your developers to follow certain parameters, you need to have a `pre-commit` hook that fails if the developers don't do it right.
- When Subversion calls your `post-commit` hook, the `PATH` environment variable has been deleted. If you need to access another command or a file, you'll have to provide the full path yourself.
- Subversion will pass you certain parameters from the *command line*. Not an actual command line, but it means you can find these parameters in `ARGV`. Two parameters will be passed to you:

  1. The repository path on the server (for the `svnlook` command).
  2. The revision of the repository.

Everything else you must deduce though `svnlook` (which you can run via the `system` command. However, since you're actually writing things in C and C++, you might be able to use the built in [Subversion API](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/api/1.7/)).

Another possibility: Use a continuous build system like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) to do the dirty work for you. You might find it easier to work through Jenkins instead of worrying how a post-commit hook might accomplish this task. One of the advantages of Jenkins is that when things go wrong, you're not sending back failed post-commit messages to the user (who is probably not at fault). Instead, you cat get a complete log of what happened, and alert the person who can actually fix the issue.

Here's a [sample of one](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Watcher-Hook/blob/master/svn-watch.pl) I wrote which is in Perl. Don't know if it'll do you any good.

Comment: We are considering using Jenkins or Team foundation server and if we use team foundation server we need to sync svn and TFS that's why i'm looking into post-commit hook.  Is there a way to use syncing functionality  for team foundation server (svn - team foundation server)?? and Thank you for the insightful reply

Comment: @kiki - Actually, you can use Jenkins to do more than just builds, and sometimes not even using it for builds. I meant solely to use Jenkins in this case just to do your syncing between Subversion and TeamFoundation.

Answer (score 2):

You can find instructions on how to define a pre-commit hook here:
http://wordaligned.org/articles/a-subversion-pre-commit-hook

The creation of a post-commit is similar to that instruction.

Once you have copied the post-commit template to a new file, you could simply add a line to call a program you have written in c++ and simply pass the arguments to your program.

It depends on what you are up to, but most of the time it is more time saving to use a scripting language as shell-script or python to do your job.

Comment: Is there an existing post-commit hook that exports the result to somewhere else or copy the codes to somewhere else (back up)?

Comment: Yes, there is a template in the svn sources: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/continuum/trunk/continuum-release/src/test/scm/hooks/post-commit.tmpl Now that you have the repository and the revision, you can simply call `svn` to get all the information you need of the commit.

Comment: I guess I need help with actually writing a script. Is there a good resource I can read or look at? with small examples to try it and get the feel of it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a stackoverflow answer here with a sample for post-commit hook on windows, using native windows shell commands - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3630534/7984