# Preventing svn commits, command line

Tags: linux, svn, command-line

I commit all my changes in use of svn (from command line). The problem I have, is that I always forget about code chill, before milestone for example, and I still commit.
I just can't think about these deadline for some reason. Can anyone tell me how can I implement a script that will print me a question on command line after I type "svn commit"?

Comment: Your release manager should be controlling this from the server end. It should not be up to the individual developer(s) to protect the repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
function svn {    
    case $1 in
        ci)
           ;;
        commit)
           ;;
        *)
           return /usr/bin/svn $@
           ;;
    esac

    echo "Did you ... ?"
    read answer
    if [ "$answer" = "yes" ] ; then
        /usr/bin/svn $@
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use svn pre-commit hook.

each time you `svn commit` the pre-commit script will be executed.

svn hooks can be written in bash, perl, python, etc even C or C++, it just need to be executable.

More info on how to write svn hooks [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773678/how-to-write-a-svn-hook-script)