# how to automate get svn commit details between two revision in excel sheet

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I want to get svn commit details between two revision and committ details should be output in excel file.
I want to have a automated script whenever any commit in new revision, script should do diff with previous and new revision and commit detail should be ouputed in excel file.

Comment: **What** you want to get this way from Excel??? Can't imagine idea

Comment: Why slow down your commits? This can be retrieved at any time in the future. Subversion is already recording all of this for you internally, why duplicate that work?

Answer (score 0):

`svn log ... --xml > filename.xml` and import this XML-file into Excel (by hand)

or

`svn diff -c REVISION --xml --summarize` inside WC after commit (server-side post-commit hook)

Comment: I need the svn diff between two revision and all diff detail should be outputed in xml or any file .. Suppose I want to see diff between rev 100 and rev 101...and it should be automated whenever any new commit then script should diff between old revision and new revision

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is have a post-commit hook script on your svn server. You can write a perl/python script to send an email of a diff between the current and the previous revision (rather modifications). We have implemented such a tool which sends out details of the revision, time of commit, username and the files modified. We do not send out the diff, but instead keep it on a web server and send the link in the email. One can simply click on the link and see the difference/modifications.
I would not recommend doing it in excel though.

To write post-commit hook you will need to know 'svnlook'. More information here: [how to write a svn hook script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773678/how-to-write-a-svn-hook-script)

The script in itself is left as an exercise.